# preg_split shortcode attributes into array

Tags: php, regex, quotes, shortcode, preg-split

I would like to parse shortcode into array via "**preg_split**".

This is example shortcode:

```
[contactform id="8411" label="This is \" first label" label2='This is second \' label']
```

and this should be result array:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 8411
    [label] => This is \" first label
    [label2] => This is second \' label
)
```

I have this regexp:

```
$atts_arr = preg_split('~\s+(?=(?:[^\'"]*[\'"][^\'"]*[\'"])*[^\'"]*$)~', trim($shortcode, '[]'));
```

Unfortunately, this works only if there is no escaping of quotes `\'` or `\"`.

Thx in advance!

Comment: `preg_split` is not the way to go, use `preg_match_all` and the `\G` anchor if you need to ensure the contiguity of the results.

Comment: I don't know whether Casimir et Hippolyte gave  a correct answer. But it is very difficult problem. I solved it by using json format for parameters in a similar situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `preg_split` is not always handy or appropriate in particular when you have to deal with escaped quotes. So, a better approach consists to use `preg_match_all`, example:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
(\w+) \s*=
(?|
    \s* "([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"
  |
    \s* '([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'
# | uncomment if you want to handle unquoted attributes
#   ([^]\s]*)
)
~xs
EOD;

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $yourshortcode, $matches)) 
    $attributes = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

The pattern uses the branch reset feature `(?|...(..)...|...(...)..)` that gives the same number(s) to the capture groups for each branch.

I was speaking about the `\G` anchor in my comment, this anchor succeeds if the current position is immediatly after the last match. It can be useful if you want to check the syntax of your shortcode from start to end at the same time (otherwise it is totally useless). Example:

```
$pattern2 = <<<'EOD'
~
(?:
    \G(?!\A) # anchor for the position after the last match
             # it ensures that all matches are contiguous
  |
    \[(?<tagName>\w+) # begining of the shortcode
)
    \s+
    (?<key>\w+) \s*=
    (?|
        \s* "(?<value>[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"
      |
        \s* '([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')
    # | uncomment if you want to handle unquoted attributes
    #   ([^]\s]*)
    )
(?<end>\s*+]\z)? # check that the end has been reached
~xs
EOD;

if (preg_match_all($pattern2, $yourshortcode, $matches) && isset($matches['end'])) 
    $attributes = array_combine($matches['key'], $matches['value']);
```

Comment: This answer solved the problem for my list of problems... The approach with **preg_match_all** is really cool, thx